# Android Beacon Library version -- 2.3.5 not detecting TI senor tag

Tags: altbeacon, android-ble

#### Mobile device model and OS version -- Nexus 5, API 23

#### Android Beacon Library version -- 2.3.5

I have a sensor tag from TI(Texas Instruments), and the firmware is TI provided.  The same 2541 chipset is used in all beacons.  I try to detect it using this library, it comes inside the didRangeBeaconsInRegion() callback but it prints beacons.size to be zero size.

Now, what changes I need to do, to get this chipset detected?

Just for further information, there are free apps in playstore named (iBeacon detector) which detects this chipset.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Did you set a `BeaconParser` on the library to detect the beacon format being transmitted?

Comment: ohhh, so I need to implement  beaconParser and for that I need to understand the sensortag protocol and then put in the implementation. Is that the way to go ahead? So this library will be able to detect this kind of BLE device which is not a beacon?

Comment: How to find the beaconLayout string for a BLE device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- The Android Beacon Library is designed to work with Bluetooth LE Beacons, not non-Beacon BLE devices.  A beacon is a specialized BLE device that continually broadcasts a unique identifier.  If you need a more general purpose BLE functionality, the library may not be a good fit.
- The TI Sensor Tag must be loaded with specific firmware to make it broadcast as a beacon.
- There are many beacon formats including AltBeacon, Eddystone and iBeacon.  If your BLE device is transmitting as a beacon you need to know which one it is transmitting.
- By default, the Android Beacon Library only detects beacon transmitters sending the AltBeacon format.  To detect other beacon formats, you must supply a `BeaconParser` for that format. A Google search will easily find the Parser expression to configure based on the format the beacon is using.

Comment: Thank You David for your time.  I am still in process of analysing. I understand your point that this lib only detects beacon transmitter, but my understanding is that a sensor tag is also transmitting data/advertisement packets but with some different protocol than a beacon. So I think I need a  different customized parser to read that?? Also, I assume, even in this lib code, you must be parsing the beacon related( protocol) specific advertisement packets. So do I need to go deep and understand the protocol followed by sensor tag?

Comment: If you are working with non-beacon communications with the Sensor Tag, then you should work with the Android Bluetooth APIs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate your support and time.